# How can I get the key pressed without hitting enter in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I get the key pressed by user without hitting the enter key in C# ?

I want to get input from console but the point is the the every key pressed must be stored in a variable as soon as the key is pressed.

So I don't need to press **ENTER key** to submit the input.

Just like `getch()` does in C++.

Comment: Give more details, about what exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Have a look at [Console.ReadKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to a console application this snippet will show all the keys pressed by a user until they hit enter to finish execution:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
        do
        {
            keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(keyinfo.Key + " was pressed");
        }
        while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    }
}
```